# How to add an object as a child of an object java

Tags: java

i'm stuck since hrs to a problem that regards adding an object as a child of another object: i have this class "Snapo" which contains the object Snapo, it is an array that contains the first index (m) which is an integer, and it's followed by a list Snapo --> [m (s1 s2 ... sn)]. Now i wrote the code to add a child which has only the "m" attribute to the main Snapo, but i can't understand how to add a Snapo to the main Snapo, like:
[8 ([5 ([7] [6])] [1 ([4] [3] [2])])] --> where "8" , "5" and "1" are the "m" and the other numbers are the list of Snapo

declaration of variables:

```
private final static int SIZE = 100;
private int m;
public int[] arr = new int[SIZE];
private int top=0;

Snapo (int m) {
    this.m = m;
    arr[0] = this.m;
}
```

This is the constructor of the class ^

```
public void addChild (Snapo s) {
    top++;
    for (int i = top; i > 1; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[1] = s.arr[0];
}
```

This is the addChild method that adds a single number to the main Snapo ^ (top is initialized as a private int = 0)

My program works with inputs like:

```
Snapo s1 = new Snapo(1);

s1.addChild(new Snapo(2));
s1.addChild(new Snapo(3));
```

But it obviously doesn't with inputs like:

```
Snapo s3 = new Snapo(8);
s3.addChild(s1);
s3.addChild(s2);
```

Comment: "it obviously doesn't"  Please explain.

Comment: i mean, if i try the last two "addChild" with s1 and s2, the output considers only the "m"s of the two Snapos discarding all the other numbers of the arrays

Comment: If a `Snapo` can be a "child" of another `Snapo`, and one `Snapo` can have many children, wouldn't it make sense for a `Snapo` to contain an array (or, better yet, a `List`) of the `Snapo`s which are its children?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is. Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] ?

Comment: @KevinAnderson i thought that could be the solution but i really don't know how to implement it..

Comment: Your `addChild` method will not compile, you did not define top.

Comment: @Abrathe problem is that the "addChild" method works with this `s1.addChild(new Snapo(2));` but not with this `s3.addChild(s1);` --> considered that "s1" and "s3" are two objects of type Snapo

Comment: @TA the variable is defined with all the other variables at the beginning of the class (private int top=0;) ; it is not a problem of variables not defined indeed i don't get any error

Comment: You should add it to your code then, it is much easier to reproduce your problem if it can be compiled.

Comment: @TA code added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example could be useful

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class TestAddC
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestAddC t= new TestAddC();
        Snapo s1 = t.new Snapo("s1");
        s1.addChild(t.new Snapo("s2"));
        Snapo s3 = t.new Snapo("s3");
        s1.addChild(s3);
        Snapo s4 = t.new Snapo("s4");
        s3.addChild(s4);

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s3);


    }
    class Snapo
    {
        List<Snapo> listC= new ArrayList<Snapo>();
        String name;
        Snapo(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void addChild(Snapo obj)
        {
            listC.add(obj);
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("parent="+this.name+"\n");
            //only first level
            listC.forEach(t->sb.append("child="+t.name+"\n"));
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
parent=s1
child=s2
child=s3

parent=s3
child=s4
```

Version 2 : with arrays

```
class TestAddC
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestAddC t= new TestAddC();
        Snapo s1 = t.new Snapo("s1");
        s1.addChild(t.new Snapo("s2"));
        Snapo s3 = t.new Snapo("s3");
        s1.addChild(s3);
        Snapo s4 = t.new Snapo("s4");
        s3.addChild(s4);
        s3.addChild(s4);
        s3.addChild(s4);
        s3.addChild(s4);
        s3.addChild(s1);

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s3);
    }
    class Snapo
    {

        //add here up to how many children
        Snapo[] listArr = new Snapo[3];
        int counter = 0;
        String name;
        Snapo(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        private int getNext()
        {
            System.out.println(counter);
            return (counter<listArr.length)? counter++ :(listArr.length -1);
        }
        public void addChild(Snapo obj)
        {
            listArr[getNext()] = obj;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("parent="+this.name+"\n");
            //only first level
            for(int i=0;i<listArr.length;i++)
            {
                if(listArr[i] instanceof Snapo )
                {
                    sb.append("child="+listArr[i].name+"\n");
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
parent=s1
child=s2
child=s3

//only 3 since arrsize is 3 (added 4, always last one have the last child)
parent=s3
child=s4
child=s4
child=s1
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without packages? i forgot to say that i must solve this exercise without using any third part package

Comment: Those imports needed for `List` , so NO in example provided and YES without imports but have to change by yourself from List to array. 3-rd Part -> ist's standard java not other packages !

Comment: yeah sorry i mean without import anything! so the only solution to the problem is to create an IntList?

Comment: added the second version with array and no imports

Comment: and if will work maybe consider as solution. Good Luck !